# Material UI text input field inside Appbar not working

Tags: node.js, material-ui

I am trying to insert two text input fields for username and password at the right of Appbar with following code. But it doesn't give the any output.

```
const AppBarExampleIconMenu = () => ( < AppBar title = { < span style = { styles.title } > Test < /span>}
            iconElementLeft = { < IconButton > < NavigationClose / > < /IconButton>}
                iconElementRight = { < div >
                    < TextField
                    hintText = "UserName" / >
                     < TextField
                    hintText = "PassWord" / >
                    < /div>
                }

                />
            );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this now. This is tested and proven working. Take note that this is written in ES6 style.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <AppBar
                    title={"Title"}
                    iconElementLeft={<IconButton iconClassName="muidocs-icon-custom-github" />}
                    iconElementRight={
                        <div>
                            <TextField
                                hintText="Username"
                            />
                            <TextField
                                hintText="Password"
                            />
                        </div>
                    }
                />

            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: why theres "Mui" everywhere. What was the import statement

Comment: sorry. I imported material-ui as Mui. You can do it without the "Mui" and just the component name.

Comment: Thanks @JanFranzPalngipang

Comment: @Jeril, sure thing.